# how do you do querySelector for no attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, attributes

given the elements:

```
<link arbitrary="arbitrary">1st link</link>
...
<link>the link I want</link>
...
```

What is the querySelector() selector for selecting "the link I want"?
There may be any number of links with arbitrary attributes before or following "the link I want", which is the only  element without any attributes. I don't want to loop through a querySelectAll() list.

[update]
querySelector doesn't require HTML elements, just plain old nodes.
I am working on an XML DOM loaded from an ATOM feed:

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlSrc, "text/xml");
var xmlElem = xmlDoc.documentElement;
// fragment:
<feed>
 <entry>
    <link rel='replies' type='application/atom+xml' href='..' title='...'/>
    <link rel='replies' type='text/html' href='...' title='...'/>
    <link>the link I want</link>
    <link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='...'/>
    <link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='...' title='...'/>
  </entry>
<feed>
```

Comment: That's an invalid attribute on an invalid element, so who knows

Comment: is this for testing/ are you using a webdriver? interacting w someone elses code via pure javascript?

Comment: You really are going to have to elaborate on what it is you're looking for if you'd like additional help.

Comment: Can you provide feedback on the latest option  added: using a custom jQuery `:hasattr` pseudo-selector to perform your selection?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one.

> The querySelector() method returns the first element that matches a specified CSS selector(s) in the document.

Because there's nothing specific about that link there isn't any way to reference it on the DOM in a sea of links that are duplicates.

Comment: "Never say never" :) I added a couple of alternatives that will do this (including a custom pseudo-selector `:hasattr` to extend jQuery).

Answer (score 0):

You could `filter` the selection, looking for an empty `attributes` property on the link node:

e.g.

```
var match = $xmlDOM.find('feed link').filter(function () {
    return this.attributes.length === 0;  // or !this.attributes.length
});
```

*As this is also about jQuery XML parsing, you really need to provide a working example to test against for this type of question.*

### Update

As you specifically want a selector that finds elements with/without attributes, you can always extend jQuery with a custom pseudo-selector like `:hasattr`

e.g.

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], {
    hasattr: function (el, index, selector){
        return el.attributes.length > 0;
    }
});
```

and use with `.find('link:not(:hasattr)')`

Comment: I am not, nor prefer to, using jQuery.  querySelector is std. level 1 API.
Thought someone would know a neat combination of :not() and [attr OP value] to do this.

Comment: @user1526089: if you *can* provide a working example of your code in a JSFiddle I will be happy to try find alternatives. We just need a testbed to avoid wasting time. :)

Comment: @user1526089: Added one of the alternatives I was thinking of. See if that suits you better :)